# Unity version where old UI such as GUIText and GUITexture was removed

Tags: unity-game-engine

In which Unity version was the old UI system removed?

For example, `GUIText` and `GUITexture`?

I want to upgrade an old Unity project to a newer version before these elements were removed, to defer dealing with error messages such as:

```
error CS0619: 'GUITexture' is obsolete: 'GUITexture has been removed. Use UI.Image instead.
error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unity 2019.3.0** removed the old UI system, even though it's not explicitly mentioned in the [2019.3 release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.3.0).

Unity 2019.2 still supports the old UI system.